# Using GitHub personal SSH key does not work for oganization repo

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying to use one of my GitHub ssh keys so that I can push and pull from an `oranization/repo`. I just created the key and added it to my own account. I followed all the instructions on [GitHub Generating SSH Keys page](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).

GitHub ssh recognizes me when I do `ssh -T git@github.com`

However, when I try to pull or clone, GitHub still asks me for username/password. I have access to modify this repository.

```
(vagrant)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant$ ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.130' to the list of known hosts.
Hi getvictor! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
(vagrant)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant$ git pull
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the remote '`origin`' of your repo:

```
git remote -v
```

If it contains https, your ssh key won't matter, because it is an https url, and not an ssh one.

You can [change it to an ssh one](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh) with:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY2.git
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're pulling over HTTPS, which doesn't know anything about your SSH keys. Try pulling from the ssh:// URL instead.